# Compressed sensing for partitioning instead of recovery

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, signal-analysis, compressed-sensing

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a signal whose support $T_0 = \{ t \mid x_{0}(t) \neq 0\}$ is assumed to be of small cardinality. The recovery of $x_0$ from a small number of $n \ll m$ linear measurements is the compressed sensing problem
$$y = Ax_{0},$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ is a sensing matrix. Obviously this is a very famous problem, with equally famous and celebrated results concerning the conditions required for the recovery of $x_0$.

But what if we do not care to recover $x_0$ completely? Instead we wish to partition $\{1, \dotsc, m \}$ into subsets $U_{i},\; i=1,\dotsc, |T_{0}|$ where $U_{i} \subset \{1, \dotsc, m\}$, $U_{i} \cap U_j =\emptyset\;\forall i,j$ and $|U_{i}\cap T_{0}|=1\;\forall i$.

In other words, we wish to find disjoint subsets $U_i \subset\{1, \dotsc, m\}$ such that for all $i$ there is only one value of $t \in U_i$ where $x_0(t)$ is nonzero.

Clearly, the conditions for recovery are sufficient to generate such a partition. However, it is not clear to me whether we can generate such a partition with significantly weaker conditions on $A$. For example, is it possible to construct these subsets with fewer measurements than would be required to recover $x_0$?

Does anyone have any insights on this? Has such a problem been studied in literature before?

---

It's been about a week and seem like no one has any ideas.

The best insight I have is as follows. Let $x_0$ be known to be a $k$-sparse vector. My thought is that the "information content" of the support of $x_0$, if treated as a random variable is something like
$$H(x_0) = \log \left( \binom{m}{k}\right) = O(k \log(m)).$$
But the information content of this partition is much lower, as shown in this paper by [Fredman and Komlos](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0605009),

$$H(U_1,\dotsc, U_k) = O(k + \log\log(m))$$

This shows nothing, but perhaps lends some credence to the idea that the partition can be constructed with fewer measurements.

Comment: how is the support set input ?

Comment: The setup is meant to exactly parallel the standard compressed sensing setup, in, for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503066.pdf by Candes and Tao (Section 1.1). It would even be of interest to deal with the case of $|T_0| = k \ll m$, where $k$ is known. Not sure if that answers your question, let me know! :)

Comment: Use `\mid` instead of `|` in $T_0 = \{ t \mid x_{0}(t) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Do you actually know a way of doing this with $O(k \log m)$ measurements? Which is the traditional entropy estimate of the subset (as opposed to the partition from Fredman/Komlos). Note that there are many famous algorithmic problems where the information theoretic lower bound has not been attained.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410542.pdf) is one of the fundamental results of CS. In section 4.1, it shows that UUP is satisfied with high probability for a gaussian i.i.d matrix when $n = O(k\log(m))$. This UUP implies that linear programing can be used to reconstruct $x_0$.